# Que hace este return en React?

Tags: reactjs, funciones

Tengo un codigo que estoy siguiendo de un curso, pero no se que hace este `return`

```
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if([pet, owner, email, date, sintomas].includes('')){
      setError(true)
    }

    //Este return
    return;
  }
```

Segun lo que creo, este return retorna el valor original del error, pero no entiendo por qué se devuelve así

Comment: Ese [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) no hace nada, excepto terminar la función. La función devuelve `undefined` como cualquier función con una sentencia `return` sin parámetro. Puedes omitirlo y funcionará igual.

Answer (score 0):

Esa es una función del useEffect la cual sirve para ejecutar algún código cuando tu componente sea destruido, esto es para tener un mejor manejo de memoria en la aplicación.

Doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html